# SYCL spec 1.2.1 (rev 7) section 4.8.9.3 error?

Tags: sycl, dpc++, intel-oneapi

Based on the code in,SYCL 1.2.1 spec (rev 7) section 4.8.9.3 I wrote the following:

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
namespace sycl = cl::sycl;
const int Nproc = 8;
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x[Nproc];
  sycl::device dev = sycl::default_selector().select_device();
  class MyKernel;
  sycl::queue myQueue(dev);
  sycl::program myProgram(myQueue.get_context());
  myProgram.build_from_name<MyKernel>();
  {
    sycl::buffer<unsigned int, 1> xbuffer((unsigned int *)x, sycl::range<1> {Nproc});
    myQueue.submit([&](sycl::handler& cgh) {
        auto xaccessor = xbuffer.get_access<sycl::access::mode::discard_write, sycl::access::target::global_buffer>(cgh);
        cgh.parallel_for<class MyKernel>(
            sycl::nd_range<1>(sycl::range<1>(Nproc),sycl::range<1>(Nproc)), 
            myProgram.get_kernel<MyKernel>(),
            [=] (sycl::nd_item<1> item) {
                xaccessor[item.get_global_linear_id()]= item.get_global_linear_id();
                }
        );
        }
        ); 
  }
  for (int i=0; i<Nproc; i++) printf("%2d   ", x[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Using OneAPI beta07 this compiles with numerous errors.

```
%dpcpp -O3 -g -mavx2 -o bug3 bug3.cpp -lOpenCL -lsycl
bug3.cpp:16:13: error: no member named 'build_from_name' in 'cl::sycl::program'
  myProgram.build_from_name<MyKernel>();
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
bug3.cpp:16:29: error: 'MyKernel' does not refer to a value
  myProgram.build_from_name<MyKernel>();
                            ^
bug3.cpp:13:9: note: declared here
  class MyKernel;
        ^
bug3.cpp:16:39: error: expected expression
  myProgram.build_from_name<MyKernel>();
                                      ^
bug3.cpp:23:13: error: no matching member function for call to 'parallel_for'
        cgh.parallel_for<class MyKernel>(
        ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/local/opt/inteloneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:807:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'range' against 'nd_range'
  void parallel_for(range<Dims> NumWorkItems, id<Dims> WorkItemOffset,
       ^
/local/opt/inteloneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:856:3: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with KernelName = MyKernel, KernelType = (lambda at bug3.cpp:26:13), Dims = 1, Reduction = cl::sycl::kernel]: no member named 'accessor_mode' in 'cl::sycl::kernel'
  parallel_for(nd_range<Dims> Range, Reduction Redu, KernelType KernelFunc) {
  ^
.
.
.
```

There seem to be a number of problems with the example in the spec.  One, there doesn't seem to be a "build_from_name" method in OneAPI nor in the spec itself.  Two, example uses both "MyProgram" and "myProgram" (minor nit but leads me to believe this isn't from verified code).  Lastly I don't recognize a parallel_for with a signature that would match that of the example.

Just curious about what's wrong.

Comment: The example uses a method that is not in the table below, but should be there. If you report it in https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SYCL-Docs/issues  the SYCL WG can address this properly.

Comment: Given the example seems to be incorrect can you explain what you are trying to achieve and perhaps someone can offer an example of how to do this using SYCL?

Comment: 1) submitted to SYCL-Docs,

2) I was trying to separate the compilation/linking of the kernel from the actual execution so I could observe overhead vs. runtime. (At least that's what I thought the code would do. The code in the post is a stripped down example and lacks the additional instrumentation that would have let me do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted the issue (way back when....)